# R For Loop Not Working

Tags: r, for-loop

Mydata set test is below. I want to create a new variable "indicator" which is=1 if all variables equal 1 (example row 3) or else 0.

```
   id    X10J X10f X10m X10ap  X10myy X10junn X10julyy
 1  1001    2    2    2     2      2       2        2
 2  1002    1    1   -1     2      1       1        1
 3  1003    1    1    1     1      1       1        1
 4  1004    1    1    2     1      1       1        1
 12 1012    1    2    1     1      1       1        1
```

i created the following for loop:

```
for (i in c(test$X10J,test$X20f,test$X10m,test$X10ap,test$Xmyy,test$X10junn,test$X10julyy)){
    if(i==1){
            test$indicator=1
    }else if(i==2|i==-1){
            test$indicator=0  
    }
}
```

this creates a variable with all values=1 instead of 0 and -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a `for` loop.  You can use `apply`

```
> test$indicator <- apply(test[-1], 1, function(x) ifelse(all(x == 1), 1, 0))
> test
     id X10J X10f X10m X10ap X10myy X10junn X10julyy indicator
1  1001    2    2    2     2      2       2        2         0
2  1002    1    1   -1     2      1       1        1         0
3  1003    1    1    1     1      1       1        1         1
4  1004    1    1    2     1      1       1        1         0
12 1012    1    2    1     1      1       1        1         0
```

Answer (score 3):

A vectorized solution:

```
test$indicator <- ifelse(rowSums(test[,-1] ==1)==ncol(test[,-1]),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

```
indicator <- apply(test[,-1], 1, function(row)
                   {
                   ifelse(all(row==1), 1, 0)
                   })
```

Note: the second parameter of `apply` is 1 if you for rows and 2 for columns.